# Limit over the integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Can anybody please help me in, when can we pass the limit like this $$\int_{\mathbf R^n}\phi(x)\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\int_{\mathbf R^n-\mathbf B(0,\epsilon)}\phi(x)\,dx$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi$ is a Lebesgue integrable function then this follows from Dominated Convergence.

If $\phi$ is not a Lebesgue integrable function then it is not entirely
clear what $\int \phi(x)\,dx$ will mean.

Comment: how would it follow from dominated convergence theorem as it is not clear that whether we would able to find some bound to our $\phi$ or not!

Comment: The dominating function would be $|\phi|$. @rs8055